# phonegap android 2.2 call javascript

Tags: android, cordova

I developing android application in phonegap I want to call javascript form my main activity.
I used the following code

appView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){alert('sfksjf'); sessionStorage.setItem('notificationTap','Yes');})();");

This works perfectly fine in android 2.1 .

but the javascript function is not called in android 2.2.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
appView.sendJavascript("(function(){alert('sfksjf'); sessionStorage.setItem('notificationTap','Yes');})();");
```

instead.